# Windows Mobile development for PIDION BIP-7000 Smart Handheld computer

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-embedded

I am about to start to developed an application for BIP-7000 Smart Handheld Computer which based on Windows CE 5.0 / Windows Mobile 6.5

http://www.mypidion.com/products/bip_7000/default.asp
http://www.mypidion.com/product/product_tab.asp?bmenu=1&t_idx=188

I need to know,

1. what should i used as the development platform from below two,

   - Windows Mobile 6.5
   - Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5
2. What is the different of these two?
3. How should I start to developed?

Comment: Just curious: Why even bother with technology so out of date? If You want to get started, try to get started with Windows Phone. The platform and corresponding SDK have been discarded.

Comment: yes i agreed with that but the device based on Windows CE 5.0 / Windows Mobile 6.5...That is why i am interested on this.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

Windows Mobile 6.5 and Windwos Embedded Handheld 6.5 are the same. Microsoft seems to use different terms or MS marketing decides to give same things different names to implicit something new. See also Pocket PC 2003 and Windows Mobile 2003, these are also the same.

And @akshay2000: although that Windows Embedded Handheld seems to be outdated, Windows Phone is NOT an option for any serious commercial developer in an industrial, professionel environment. Or do you use a smartphone to scan articles in a stocking warehouse? The successor for Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 for industrial use is Windows Embedded Compact and Windows CE 6 etc.